# How to add multiple example values for an array in OpenAPI/Swagger?

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I am using Swagger OpenAPI Specification tool. I have a string array property in one of the definitions as follows:

```
cities:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
      example: "Pune"
```

My API produces JSON result, so Swagger UI displays the following example for the response:

```
{
  "cities": [
    "Pune"
  ]
}
```

How can I add multiple example values for the `cities` array? Expecting the result as:

```
{
  "cities": [
    "Pune",
    "Mumbai",
    "Bangaluru"
  ]
}
```

Tried comma-separated strings in the `example` key like below:

```
cities:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
      example: "Pune", "Mumbai", "Bangaluru"
```

But the Swagger Editor shows an error, "Bad indentation".

Is there any way to specify multiple values in the `example` key?

**Update**

User Helen below has given the correct answer. I had an indentation problem hence there were nested arrays (2d arrays)

Correct way:

```
cities:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
    example: 
    - Pune
    - Mumbai
```

My way (which was wrong)

```
cities:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
      example: 
      - Pune
      - Mumbai
```

Look for the indentation of the `example` key in the above two cases which makes the difference, its YAML indentation matters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To display an array example with multiple items, add the `example` on the array level instead of item level:

```yaml
cities:
  type: array
  items:
    type: string
  example:
    - Pune
    - Mumbai
    - Bangaluru

  # or
  # example: [Pune, Mumbai, Bangaluru]
```

In case of array of objects, the `example` would look like this:

```yaml
type: array
items:
  type: object
  properties:
    id:
      type: integer
    name:
      type: string
example:
  - id: 1
    name: Prashant
  - id: 2
    name: Helen
```

Comment: the solution you have given outputs "cities": [
    [
      "Pune",
      "Mumbai"
    ]
  ] this, which is two nested arrays which I don't want I want single array holding these names as array elements not as new arrays, Thanks for response

Comment: Where do you see nested arrays? It works fine in the Swagger Editor:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT85I.png

Comment: Hey thanks Helen indentation was the problem see updated question.

Comment: @Prashant is right, this approach is displayed as array (both Swagger Editor and Swagger UI). There is an `examples` option, but still not clear how to use it within `components/schemas`. See https://www.viralpatel.net/openapi-multiple-examples/, and https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/.

Answer (score -1):

paths:
/products_1:
get:
responses:
'200':
description: "XYZ"
content:
application/json:
schema:
type: array
items:
$ref: '#/components/schemas/pro'
example:
- name : "Laptop"
dist : "HP LAPTOP"
- name : "Mobile"
dist : "Apple Mobile"

components:
schemas:
pro:
type: object
properties:
prodName:
type: string
example: "Laptop"
prodDesc:
type: string
example: "Produc Description"

Answer (score -3):

For openapi version - 3.0.0+

```
  major:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        enum:
          - Accounting
          - Business Contacts
          - Economy
          - Finance
          - Graphic Design
          - International Business Administration
          - International Relations
          - Law
          - Marketing
          - others
          - Political Science
          - Statistics
```

Comment: This is not what the question is about. Your answer shows an array of an enum, whereas the question is asking how to specify a multi-value array as an _example value_ for an array schema.