# How to provide string array (default values) in the swagger definition

Tags: swagger

### Currently, my swagger definition has :

`"MyAttribute": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": "item1",
      "enum": [
        "item1",
        "item2"
      ],
      "xml": {
        "attribute": true
      }
    },`

Swagger codegen generates this java code:

@XmlEnum(String.class)
public enum MyAttribute{

```
@XmlEnumValue("item1")
item1("item1"),

@XmlEnumValue("item2")
item2("item2");

private String value;

/**
 * @param value the string representation of the map specification type attribute
 */
MyAttribute(final String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return String.valueOf(value);
}
```

}

Now, I want to have a string array(with values) instead of enum. 
I tried this (but shows errors on swagger website : http://editor.swagger.io/)

`"MyAttribute": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "values": [
          "item1",
          "item2"
        ]
      },
      "xml": {
        "attribute": true
      }
    }`

How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want an array of enum (i.e. array items are enum values), or an _example_ of a multi-item array?

Comment: I want a multi item array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple example values in swagger propertise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578110/how-to-add-multiple-example-values-in-swagger-propertise), also [Return an array of object in SwaggerHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46167981/113116)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It helped.