# Swagger OAS3.0 Multiple responses in the same response code

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I am using Swagger Hub to generate API and wanting to get multiple responses for the get request: https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/factly/test/1.0.0/categories

Following is how I defined my API. When I execute the API I only get one category in response. How do I get all the three categories defined as a response? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  description: This is the sample API for Core
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: Dega Core API
tags:
  - name: Core
    description: Operations related to Core
paths:
  /categories:
    get:
      tags:
        - Core
      summary: gets all the categories
      description: this is to get all the available categories
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/CategoryItem'
              examples:
                category1:
                  $ref: '#/components/examples/category1'
                category2:
                  $ref: '#/components/examples/category2' 
                category3:
                  $ref: '#/components/examples/category3'
components:
  schemas:
    CategoryItem:
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - name
        - slug
        - createdDate
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
          example: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
        name:
          type: string
          example: Category 1
        slug:
          type: string
          example: category-1
        description:
          type: string
          example: This is a sample category
        parent:
          type: string
          example: null
        createdDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
          example: '2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z'
  examples:
    category1:
      value:
        id: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
        name: Category 1
        slug: category-1
        description: This is the sample description for Category 1
        parent: null
        createdDate: '2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z'
    category2:
      value:
        id: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
        name: Category 2
        slug: category-2
        description: This is the sample description for Category 2
        parent: null
        createdDate: '2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z'
    category3:
      value:
        id: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
        name: Category 3
        slug: category-3
        description: This is the sample description for Category 3
        parent: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
        createdDate: '2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z'
servers:
  - url: 'https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/factly/test/1.0.0'
```

The response I am expecting is the following:

```
[{
    "id": "d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851",
    "name": "Category 1",
    "slug": "category-1",
    "description": "This is the sample description for Category 1",
    "createdDate": "2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z"
},
{
    "id": "d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851",
    "name": "Category 2",
    "slug": "category-2",
    "description": "This is the sample description for Category 2",
    "createdDate": "2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z"
},
{
    "id": "d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851",
    "name": "Category 3",
    "slug": "category-3",
    "description": "This is the sample description for Category 3",
    "parent": "d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851",
    "createdDate": "2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z"
}]
```

Thanks,
Shashi

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "get all the three categories defined as a response"? Do you expect to mock to cycle through the category1, category2 and category3 responses sequentially? Or something else?

Comment: Hi Helen, thanks for your response. I updated the question with the response object I am expecting when I query the API. Thanks.

Comment: Similar questions about OpenAPI 2.0: [How to add an array example with multiple values in Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46578110/113116), [Return an array of objects in SwaggerHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46167981/113116)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So your response is an array of objects, and you want to specify the response `example` containing an array with multiple items.

There are several ways to specify examples for array responses, but in any case the **example must be a complete example**, that is you cannot $ref'erence *parts* of an example (such as the values of individual array items). In other words, the example value cannot be built from partial $refs.

You can put the `example` inside your array schema, alongside `type: array`:

```yaml
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/CategoryItem'
                example:
                  - id: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
                    name: Category 1
                    slug: category-1
                    description: This is the sample description for Category 1
                    createdDate: '2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z'
                  - id: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
                    name: Category 2
                    slug: category-2
                    description: This is the sample description for Category 2
                    createdDate: '2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z'
                  - id: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
                    name: Category 3
                    slug: category-3
                    description: This is the sample description for Category 3
                    parent: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
                    createdDate: '2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z'
```

Or add the `example` alongside the response `schema`:

```yaml
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/CategoryItem'
              example:
                - id: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
                  name: Category 1
                  slug: category-1
                  description: This is the sample description for Category 1
                  createdDate: '2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z'
                - id: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
                  ...
```

Or if you want to specify a description for the example, use the `examples` keyword (plural) as shown below. (But `examples` are currently [not displayed](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2651) in Swagger UI.)

```yaml
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/CategoryItem'
              examples:
                categoryWithThreeItems:
                  summary: Example of a category with three items
                  value:
                    - id: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
                      name: Category 1
                      slug: category-1
                      description: This is the sample description for Category 1
                      createdDate: '2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z'
                    - id: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
                      ...
```

or put the whole example to the `components/example` section and `$ref` it. Note again, we can `$ref` whole examples only but not parts of an example.

```yaml
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/CategoryItem'
              examples:
                categoryWithThreeItems:
                  $ref: '#/components/examples/categoryWithThreeItems'
components:
  examples:
    categoryWithThreeItems:
      summary: Example of a category with three items
      value:
        - id: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
          name: Category 1
          slug: category-1
          description: This is the sample description for Category 1
          createdDate: '2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z'
        - id: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
          ...
```

Comment: Hi Helen, Thanks again for your detailed response. I am looking for a solution where the example is reusable. The reason I was using $ref: '#/components/examples/category1' is to reuse the category within other responses as well?

Comment: I added an example of using `#/components/examples` to specify the array value. As for the `category1`, `category2`, etc. examples from your original question - you can use them as standalone examples (e.g. in resources that accept/return a single category), but it's not possible to build the array example by combining $ref'erenced examples. $refs are not resolved inside `example` and `examples.<name>.value`; the content of these keys is taken as is, as a literal example value.